# Assert interface to slice of struct

Tags: go, interface

Why am I facing error that first arg to append must be slice after being already asserted interface to a slice of structs?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type AccessKeys struct {
    AccessKeys interface{}
}

type AccessKey struct {
    AccessKeyID string
}

func main() {
    var b AccessKey
    b.AccessKeyID = "ye"

    var bs AccessKeys
    bs.AccessKeys = bs.AccessKeys.([]AccessKey) // Assert
    bs.AccessKeys = append(bs.AccessKeys, b) // Error: first argument to append must be slice; have interface {}
    
    fmt.Println(bs)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/OfT3i1AbkMe

Comment: Here (`bs.AccessKeys = bs.AccessKeys.([]AccessKey)`) you are asserting it to `[]AccessKey` only to write it back into an `interface{}`. Basically this line does nothing -- apart from panicking if `bs.AccessKeys` is not of type `[]AccessKey`. It would be nice though to know what you are actually trying to do. Working with `interface{}` should be a very rare exception in Go and not be used by beginners at all.

Comment: Hey @TehSphinX, can you tell why will it panic?

Comment: There are 2 types of type assertions: `b := someVar.(someType)` will panic if `someVar` is not of type `someType`. Then there is `b, ok := someVar.(someType)` which will return `ok == false` if `someVar` is not of type `someType`. If you are not 100% sure that `someVar` is of type `someType`, I'd always use the latter.

Comment: @TehSphinX what I meant was why the above example would panic? `interface{}` should be able to be asserted as almost any signature.

Comment: There always is an underlying type under `interface{}`. If that type is not the same as you are asserting it will panic, unless you use the `v, ok := ...` assertion. For example if there is a `string` in the `interface{}` and you try to assert it to an `int`: `var val interface{} = "hello"` This will panic: `intVal := val.(int)`. Note that assertion IS NOT conversion! An assertion never converts a variable to a different type. It only checks if the existing (underlying type) is of type X or implements type X.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the section on empty interfaces in this video from Rob Pike: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAAkCSZUG1c&t=7m36s (on my general comment why it should rarely be used)

Comment: It might also help to read up on conversion vs assertion. e.g. https://www.sohamkamani.com/golang/type-assertions-vs-type-conversions/

Comment: @TehSphinX Thanks for the links above. The link above says that `Type assertions can only take place on interfaces.`. The above interface is of **untyped** nil which can't be asserted to anything else. Is it so?

Comment: That is correct, yes. Note that if an interface is filled by a value or by nil (typed and untyped) is a runtime issue and cannot be statically checked (e.g. by the compiler). Making this something to be extra aware of. Also making the assertion `v, ok := someVal.(someType)` extra valuable as even a `nil` can lead to a panic on a non-safe assertion.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot work because you try to append AccessKey to type interface{} which is not a slice.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type AccessKeys struct {
    AccessKeys []interface{}
}

type AccessKey struct {
    AccessKeyID string
}

func main() {
    var b AccessKey
    b.AccessKeyID = "ye"

    var bs AccessKeys
    bs.AccessKeys = append(bs.AccessKeys, b)
    
    fmt.Println(bs)
}
```

But in my opinion this is not very idiomatic way to do something, but depends what are you trying to achieve. What I would even replace

> AccessKeys []interface{}
> with
> AccessKeys []AccessKey

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to a kind poster who deleted his comment later.

It doesn't work because `AccessKeys interface{}` makes AccessKeys an *untyped* nil type as the zero value for an interface is *untyped* nil. As Go is a statically typed language, it will give an error at compile time.

If this makes sense, its for the same reason you can't do this in Go:

```
n := nil
```

Even if that is fixed, it will fail at runtime while asserting saying `panic: interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not []main.AccessKey`. Though I am not sure why.